# How to stop sqlitedatareader from returning 0 if data is null?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datareader

I am trying to fetch data of 1 column from a table in an SQLite database using the below code.

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", filePath));
m_dbConnection.Open();    
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
{ 
// Select query here
}
var command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
List<object> data = new List<object>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader[0].GetType() == typeof(DBNull)) // Always gives False
       data.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    else
       data.Add(reader.GetValue(0));
}
```

But `DBNull` check always returns false even if there is null in the DataBase. Thus, here the `reader.GetValue(0)` is called and that converts the **`DBNull` to 0**.

**NOTE :** The data type of the column to be fetched is `int`

I don't want this `DBNull` to get converted to 0. If I do it like this then my task is achieved.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  try
  {
     data.Add(reader.GetString(0));
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
     data.Add(reader.GetValue(0));                           
  }                                                                  
}
```

But it is wrong way because in majority case exception will be thrown, only when the data is `DBNull` then the exception will not occur.

Please suggest a way to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Right check for REAL DbNull value is:

```
string value;
if (dataReader.IsDBNull(0)) value = "";
else value = dataReader.GetString(0);
```

And if you have string "null"

```
string value = dataReader.GetString(0);
if(value.ToLower()=="null")value="";
```

Comment: Not working  !! Even here `if(reader.IsDBNull(0))' always returns false. It is not returning true if value is null.

Comment: wow wow. Are you shure that there is REAL DbNull? Or there is just string 'null'? Because this code is work just perfect for DbNull's

Comment: I am sure it is not string because when I pass it like `String str = reader[0] as String` , `str` returns me `null`.

Comment: Wrong answer. Put break point and look what exactly value is in there! Not necessary that there is null, `as` could return null if there int value, or byte. In other words - make shure that `0` is `string` column, and it could be `null` in database

Comment: I have mentioned in the question also, that the column's datatype is `int` but it also contains DBNull values. Put the breakpoint and check is the very first thing I did. It is DBNull I have cross verified

Comment: Maybe we should go to chat? Lets try to figureout whats wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137426/discussion-between-jdoshi-and-sergio).